# Yahoo Finance quotes CSV link broken

Tags: yahoo-finance

I am in the middle of updating an older website. I noticed it's trying to grab data from "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=CADUSD=X". However, this link no longer works...does anyone have any idea where I should be looking instead?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Yahoo no longer offers this service...I ended up using https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/